# How do I continue to allow the user to click until a certain point?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jbirdwell/YEmat/1/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src='script.js'></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src = "http://www.nba.com/media/playerfile/thunder_logo.gif"/><img id="champion" src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4018/4624684843_1630196e78.jpg"/><div id="ball"></div>&nbsp;<div id="ball"></div>&nbsp;<div id="ball"></div> <div id="ball"></div> <div id="ball"></div> <div id="ball"></div> <div id="ball"></div> <div id="ball"></div> <div id="ball"></div> <div id="ball"></div> <div id="ball"></div>  
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ball = 11;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ball').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        ball -= 1;
        if(ball === 0){
            $('#champion').css("display",'inline-block');
        }
    });


});
```

CSS:

```
#ball{
        background-color: orange;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #FF8A21;
        display: inline-block;
}
#champion{
    display: none;
    width: 45px;
    }
```

I have a couple of questions.

How do I continue to let the #ball to be faded out until they are all gone?

How can I multiple the basketball instead of having to put  every time I want a ball?

Comment: Please create a SSCCE on jsfiddle.net

Comment: And what do you mean by _put_ do you want 11 balls on the page or one ball 11 times, and in random positions?

Comment: IDs ***MUST*** be unique! Change `id=ball` to `class=ball` and `$('#ball').click()` to `$('.ball').click()`

Comment: In the html I have to put <div id="ball"></div> for each time I want a basketball is there way I can set an integer to display a certain number of them. The main problem is trying to let the user click them until all of them are gone.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jbirdwell/YEmat/1/

Comment: Dom that worked! Thank you. This is my second day learning html and css and jQuery. I am really encouraged by how great the community is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the id to class. It's not working correctly because you can just have one ID at a time. here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/qh7St/2/

```
  $('.ball').click(function()

  <div class="ball"></div>
```

I'm not sure if I fully understand your second question. do you mean how would you dynamically add the balls instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: Exactly, on the second part.

Comment: I've updated the code, you will use html.append() check it out and let me know if that's what you were looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/qh7St/2/

Comment: That is gorgeous! I added a space between each one now. I am doing this for a fun side project. I will add the other teams left in the playoffs soon.http://jsfiddle.net/jbirdwell/qh7St/3/

Comment: Cool, btw are you an OKC fan?

Comment: Now that I am trying to add two rows of basketballs it will not. http://jsfiddle.net/jbirdwell/qh7St/4/

Comment: that's because you have 2 instances of the same ID. changed it to ball2: http://jsfiddle.net/qh7St/7/